# how to use property to set style dynamically?

Tags: angular, properties, styles

I am using Angular2, I would like to set the style dinamically using property names in component. Following is what I have tried, but it is not working.

```
<span class = "label" [style.background-color]="property1+'_css'">{{property1}} </span>
<span class = "label" [style.background-color]="property2+'_css'">{{property2}} </span>

export class ABC implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    property1 : string = "#f89406";
    property2 : string = "#3a87ad";
}
```

If someone knows about it, could you give some advice?

---

I rephrazed my words, I wanted to change background color according to item name like codes below. I have properties like below in the component. item1, item2 and item3 points to {{item.name}} in the template. It is fine to code statistically css name according to item name. But I do want to suffix with _css for those properties. So, I put '_css' at the end. Also, right to the [style.background-color] is not the property defined directly in the component, it is variable defined in the ngFor of template.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
       <b><span class = "label" [style.background-color]="item.name+'_css'">{{item.name}}</span></b>
</tr>

export class ABC implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    item1_css : string = "#f89406";
    item2_css : string = "#3a87ad";
    item3_css : string = "#2283c5";
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What is the purpose of the `'_css'` part?

Comment: Still not sure what you try to accomplish. I added an answer below what my suspicion is you might want.

Comment: I think my point is that the background color is determined based on the item, which is dynamically displayed within ngFor. In other words, in the "item.name+'_css'", item.name is not the defined in component directly. It is  under ngFor.

Comment: I think I got it. I updated my answer. You need some helper on the component because `this` is not allowed in the template AFAIK. You can try `this` instead of `self` in the view and ignore the getter.

Comment: You are aware that a `<tr>` can't contain a `<b>` element? only an `<td>`

Answer (score 1):

```
[style.background-color]="self[item.name +'_css']"
```

```
get self() {
  return this;
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/HVKGx8uYRpbf88Jo75W5?p=preview)

Comment: It does not work against my expectation. I do not understand well also.

Comment: It just shows one color (default color of label), does not show any error.

Comment: What do you get when you add `<pre>{{self[item.name +'_css']}}</pre>`

Comment: Value is corrected set like #f89406, if then, what could be the problem? It might be other problem :)

Comment: <span class = "label" [style.background-color]="self[item.name + '_css']">

.label { border-radius: 7px; text-shadow: none; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; padding: 3px 5px 3px; background-color: #abbac3!important }

The reason I add [style.background-color] is to overwrite the background-color over defaul label's background color.

Comment: I added a Plunker example.

Comment: If the default has `!important` you can't just overwrite it.

Comment: Thank you so so so much for your kind reply. If you do not mind, could I ask one more question? :) In previous question, the color was determined based on the whole name of item like 'item1', 'item2' and 'item3'. But I came to need to determine the color by the first character of item name. For example, I assume, the item name have ABC, BCD, CDE and ACD. Each item's color is determined depending on the first character of that item name for example, A, B, C. I tried this based on the codes you showed me. But I still can't resolve it. Could you please help me once more?

Comment: You're welcome :) `self[item.name.charAt(0) +'_css']` should do what you want if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand purpose of using **`_css`** but you could do following,

```
[style.backgroundColor]="property1"
```

OR

```
[style.background-color]="property1"
```

Answer (score 0):

considering that you are trying to add `css class` to element
otherwise @micronyks is providing exact code.

```
[ngClass]="{'my-class_css': isClassVisible }"
```